# Why data binding doesn't always work with primitives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

One of the milestones in learning JS and Angular, is learning that two way data binding with primitives is tricky. If you want to make sure that databinding works, you should always pack it into an object - that is what I was told by some seniors in my company. My question is - why is that happening? What is exactly going on that makes databinding with primitives so compliated in JS?

I found out that Javascript passes objects by reverence, and primitives by value. So what exactly happens in for example AngularJS Controller, that enables us to bind primitive in ngModel?

**EDIT**

Any articles, pointers are more than welcome!

Comment: Objects are references and the content of references can be edited. Primitives are just values and are not bound to a variable. So, if you have an object and pass its reference to e.g. a directive, you can make changes to the same object. If you just pass the value of e.g. an integer and edit it, it won't be updated on the initial place. By wrapping the integer into an object, you'll get a reference again and both sides can make their changes.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3, that makes sense. How about Angular controllers? How do they work with primitives? You can use ngModel on int, and it will auto update.

Comment: In your HTML, you can define the variable with ng-model. The value however is stored in the $scope object. You can access every ngModel key through that object. If you have <input ng-model="tel">, you can access the integer by using $scope.tel. So, everything is wrapped in an object.

Answer (score 1):

Here is good [post](http://zcourts.com/2013/05/31/angularjs-if-you-dont-have-a-dot-youre-doing-it-wrong/#sthash.NvNbmUpt.dpbs) or [post](http://www.codelord.net/2014/05/10/understanding-angulars-magic-dont-bind-to-primitives/).
In short:

**"Primitive values (e.g. numbers, strings) are immutable in JavaScript. So whenever a change is made to them it means we are actually throwing away the previous instance and using a different one."**